# Multiple definition of class methods when building shared library

Tags: c++, linker, scons

I'm building a C++ library using SConstruct.  If I build the library as a static library, everything works as expected.

However, if I try to build the library as a shared library, I get a huge list of 'multiple definition of' errors when linking.

I don't understand why it is throwing these errors - as far as I can tell, I am not defining these methods multiple times.  It does seem that these methods are `virtual`, which may or may not be a factor.

Relavant files:
[ISceneManager.hpp](https://github.com/jarrettchisholm/glr/blob/master/include/ISceneManager.hpp)
[BasicSceneManager.hpp](https://github.com/jarrettchisholm/glr/blob/master/include/BasicSceneManager.hpp) (inherits from `ISceneManager`)
[BasicSceneManager.cpp](https://github.com/jarrettchisholm/glr/blob/master/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp)

An excerpt of the errors:

```
build/BasicSceneManager.os: In function `glr::BasicSceneManager::drawAll()':
/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:81: multiple definition of `glr::BasicSceneManager::drawAll()'
build/BasicSceneManager.os:/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:81: first defined here
build/BasicSceneManager.os: In function `glr::BasicSceneManager::setDefaultShaderProgram(glr::shaders::IShaderProgram*)':
/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:118: multiple definition of `glr::BasicSceneManager::setDefaultShaderProgram(glr::shaders::IShaderProgram*)'
build/BasicSceneManager.os:/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:118: first defined here
build/BasicSceneManager.os: In function `glr::BasicSceneManager::getModelMatrix() const':
/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:128: multiple definition of `glr::BasicSceneManager::getModelMatrix() const'
build/BasicSceneManager.os:/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:128: first defined here
build/BasicSceneManager.os: In function `glr::BasicSceneManager::getShaderProgramManager() const':
/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:133: multiple definition of `glr::BasicSceneManager::getShaderProgramManager() const'
build/BasicSceneManager.os:/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:133: first defined here
build/BasicSceneManager.os: In function `glr::BasicSceneManager::getCamera() const':
/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:162: multiple definition of `glr::BasicSceneManager::getCamera() const'
build/BasicSceneManager.os:/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:162: first defined here
build/BasicSceneManager.os: In function `glr::BasicSceneManager::destroyCamera()':
/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:236: multiple definition of `glr::BasicSceneManager::destroyCamera()'
build/BasicSceneManager.os:/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:236: first defined here
build/BasicSceneManager.os: In function `glr::BasicSceneManager::getBillboardManager() const':
/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:276: multiple definition of `glr::BasicSceneManager::getBillboardManager() const'
build/BasicSceneManager.os:/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:276: first defined here
build/BasicSceneManager.os: In function `glr::BasicSceneManager::getModelManager() const':
/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:281: multiple definition of `glr::BasicSceneManager::getModelManager() const'
build/BasicSceneManager.os:/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:281: first defined here
build/BasicSceneManager.os: In function `glr::BasicSceneManager::getNumSceneNodes() const':
/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:311: multiple definition of `glr::BasicSceneManager::getNumSceneNodes() const'
build/BasicSceneManager.os:/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:311: first defined here
build/BasicSceneManager.os: In function `glr::BasicSceneManager::getNumLights() const':
/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:316: multiple definition of `glr::BasicSceneManager::getNumLights() const'
build/BasicSceneManager.os:/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:316: first defined here
build/BasicSceneManager.os: In function `glr::BasicSceneManager::getEnvironmentManager()':
/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:299: multiple definition of `glr::BasicSceneManager::getEnvironmentManager()'
build/BasicSceneManager.os:/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:299: first defined here
build/BasicSceneManager.os: In function `glr::BasicSceneManager::getTerrainManager(glr::terrain::IFieldFunction*)':
/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:287: multiple definition of `glr::BasicSceneManager::getTerrainManager(glr::terrain::IFieldFunction*)'
build/BasicSceneManager.os:/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:287: first defined here
build/BasicSceneManager.os: In function `glr::BasicSceneManager::getSceneNode(glr::Id) const':
/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:138: multiple definition of `glr::BasicSceneManager::getSceneNode(glr::Id) const'
build/BasicSceneManager.os:/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:138: first defined here
build/BasicSceneManager.os: In function `glr::BasicSceneManager::getLight(glr::Id) const':
/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:167: multiple definition of `glr::BasicSceneManager::getLight(glr::Id) const'
build/BasicSceneManager.os:/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:167: first defined here
build/BasicSceneManager.os: In function `glr::BasicSceneManager::getSceneNode(std::string const&) const':
/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:150: multiple definition of `glr::BasicSceneManager::getSceneNode(std::string const&) const'
build/BasicSceneManager.os:/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:150: first defined here
build/BasicSceneManager.os: In function `glr::BasicSceneManager::getLight(std::string const&) const':
/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:179: multiple definition of `glr::BasicSceneManager::getLight(std::string const&) const'
build/BasicSceneManager.os:/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:179: first defined here
build/BasicSceneManager.os: In function `glr::BasicSceneManager::getDefaultShaderProgram() const':
/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:123: multiple definition of `glr::BasicSceneManager::getDefaultShaderProgram() const'
build/BasicSceneManager.os:/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:123: first defined here
build/BasicSceneManager.os: In function `glr::BasicSceneManager::destroySceneNode(glr::ISceneNode*)':
/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/src/BasicSceneManager.cpp:221: multiple definition of `glr::BasicSceneManager::destroySceneNode(glr::ISceneNode*)'
```

Does anyone have any idea why I would get these errors?

Comment: This is more of a build tool/process question than a C++ question. The linker won't lie, so clearly you must have multiple definitions. What I would do is look at the final link that is building your .so. That probably has a bunch of .o's in it. Run nm on each .o, and find where the multiply defined symbol is coming from. Run output through c++filt to demangle.

Comment: On the other hand, this might be a common problem that results from a common error in using SConstruct, so you might be better off trying their support mechanisms.

Comment: awesome, I didn't know about `nm`.  I'll start looking through it - thanks @kec!

Comment: So I looked in each `.os` file, and there is only one definition in `BasicSceneManager.os`.  I'll look into a possible `SConstruct` issue.

Comment: Do you know how to use `find`? If so, you can use `find` to run `nm` on *everything* on your computer in one command-line.

Comment: Also, you need to run `nm` on *everything* from the actual link command, including libraries, etc, not just the `.os` files that you know about. I'm not sure whether or not scons is showing that by default, or you need to do something special with scons to show all verbose details.

Comment: Yeah, I ran a bash script that searched for all files with `*.os` and then ran `nm` on them.  I didn't know I had to look through libraries, I could try that next.

Comment: You were right, it was an `SCons` issue - I was sending duplicate file names to the linker (by including my `src` directory twice in the source files list).  Getting rid of the duplicate fixed the issue!  If you want, feel free to add that as an answer and I'll accept it! (issue is documented here: http://www.mrao.cam.ac.uk/~bn204/alma/sweng/sconsintro.html#shared-library-builder)

Comment: Best if you post the answer yourself, if SO allows that, since I have never used SCons, so I'm sure that your answer would be more clear and helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with `SConstruct`.

I collect my source files using the `Glob` command, like so:

```
source_files = Glob('build/*.cpp')
source_files = source_files + Glob('build/exceptions/*.cpp')
source_files = source_files + Glob('build/gui/*.cpp')
source_files = source_files + Glob('build/gui/cef/*.cpp')
source_files = source_files + Glob('build/models/*.cpp')
source_files = source_files + Glob('build/*.cpp')
source_files = source_files + Glob('build/environment/*.cpp')
source_files = source_files + Glob('build/terrain/*.cpp')
source_files = source_files + Glob('build/terrain/marching_cubes/*.cpp')
source_files = source_files + Glob('build/serialize/*.cpp')
...

env.SharedLibrary('build/glr', source_files, LIBS = libraries, LIBPATH = library_paths)
```

The problem was that I had a duplicate `source_files = source_files + Glob('build/*.cpp')` line, which caused certain source files to be included twice in the linker.

Removing that duplicate line, it worked just fine.

This was only an issue with the `SharedLibrary` builder - it did not happen when using the `StaticLibrary` builder.  This issue is documented [here](http://www.mrao.cam.ac.uk/~bn204/alma/sweng/sconsintro.html#shared-library-builder).

Thanks to kec for help diagnosing this issue.